# If response text contains html means not displaying as html if we are using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**Html side:**

```html
  <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="data.myText"></div>

value for data.myText is  <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #cc99ff; background-color: #ff00ff;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 24pt;">test</span></span>
```

As an expected output, the text is needed to be displayed with the following styles.

But actual, the result is not displaying styles.

If anyone knows any means how to fix this, please update.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? Also provide your code, with what you have tried so far.

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: yes. please refresh and check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your angularjs versions? With 1.2, you can do

```
<div ng-bind-html='data.myText'></div>
```

and `data.myText` must convert by `$sce`, you can inject `$sce` to you controller like:

```
var myCtrl = function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.data.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml('value for data.myText is  <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: #cc99ff; background-color: #ff00ff;"><span style="font-family: helvetica; font-size: 24pt;">test</span></span>');
};
```

That works well in [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/cehenuxepi/1/)